# Adding Data to a linked table for multiple records on the main table

Tags: ms-access

I've One to many linked tables by a short text field "ItemID", the main table contains 100s of records and the linked table is blank & contains 3 fields; "ID", "ItemID" and "Job".  As shown on the attached [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWqeU.jpg).
Is it possible to filter the main table by any of its fields then insert records into the linked table for all filtered record on the main table?
  e.g. to filter the main table by material "wood" & then to add "job"s on the linked table for all filtered items.
 Note: I used Multi Values Field for Job on the main table before but I changed to a linked table due to its difficulty for selecting, copying, editing and erasing.

Comment: you should really show the structure of your table with some data, and the results you want. You are mixing diffrent things (it doesnt make sense to filter anything to insert other things) and that is very confusing

Comment: @ThomasG I attached an example

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the "material" filter for instance.

In order to achieve what you want, you must have a third table "Material_Jobs", listing all the steps for each kind of material, and their order (you should know that *cutting* comes before *painting* for instance)

Something like

```
 ID | Material  |  Job_Name | Step_Order
 ---------------------------------------
 1  | Wood      |  Cutting  | 1
 2  | Wood      |  Welding  | 2
 3  | Wood      |  Painting | 3
 4  | CS        |  Forming  | 1
 5  | CS        |  Welding  | 2
 6  | CS        |  Painting | 3
```

Then what you can do is :

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (ItemID, JobID)
SELECT T1.ItemID, T2.ID 
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Material_Job T2 ON T1.Material = T2.Material
WHERE T1.Material='Wood'
ORDER BY T2.Step_Order
```

It's a very simplistic explanation but you should hopefully have a better idea now

Comment: Thank you Thomas, I followed your proposal but unfortunately not succeeded. I shared the sample access file [link] (https://1drv.ms/u/s!Anrs1YfNb11Sgvs7Q30EreRnIl147A)